# I can't figure out how to refer to my template from a Django view

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and cannot figure out what the path to my templates is supposed to look like. My project's directory tree looks like this:

```
blog
blog/blog
blog/blog/__init__.pyc
blog/blog/wsgi.pyc
blog/blog/urls.py
blog/blog/urls.pyc
blog/blog/wsgi.py
blog/blog/__init__.py
blog/blog/settings.py
blog/blog/settings.pyc
blog/home
blog/home/views.py
blog/home/templates
blog/home/templates/home
blog/home/templates/home/main.html
blog/home/__init__.pyc
blog/home/urls.py
blog/home/urls.pyc
blog/home/models.py
blog/home/tests.py
blog/home/__init__.py
blog/home/views.pyc
blog/manage.py
```

Here is my view (from `blog/home/view.py`):

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home/main.html", {"name" : "maxwell"})
```

A redacted copy of my settings.py file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/UMTepK9j

And finally, here is the error I get when I browse to `127.0.0.1:8000`:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/main.html
```

Can anyone tell me what the path ought to look like in my call to `render_to_response`?

Comment: Could we see your settings.py?

Comment: @Jeff Edited post to include link to a copy of my settings.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your settings.py should point to the `template` folder.

Should be something like this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '../home/templates'
)
```

That should work.

Note: There you're using relative paths which is not recommended. You should have something like this in your `settings.py`:

```
import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))

...

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../home/templates/'),
)
```

Also, you're calling `render_to_response` without passing it a `RequestContext`. With this, your templates will lack of some variables important for your project like `user`. It's better to call it this way:

```
return render_to_response(
    "home/main.html",
    context_instance=RequestContext(
        request,
        {'name':'maxwell'}
    )
)
```